# How to refresh relationship before deleting entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to delete an entity that has a @OneToMany relationship with another one, set up like this:

```
public class Dealership implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dealership", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Car> cars;
}

public class Car implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="co_id") 
    private Dealership dealership;

}
```

The thing is that, when I delete the dealership, I want to delete only the cars that were not sold. And no matter what I try, Hibernate deletes ALL cars tied with the dealership, through the cascade. Here's what I've been trying. In this example, I'm trying to transfer the sold cars to another dealership, and then I delete the dealership. This is supposed to delete the dealership, its employees, and ONLY the cars that were not sold:

```
Session session = SessionManager.getSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Dealership dealershipToDelete = (Dealership) session.load(Dealership.class, idDealership);

for(Car c: dealershipToDelete.getCars().stream().filter(c -> c.isSold()).toArray(Car[]::new)){
    Dealership newDealership = (Dealership) session.load(Dealership.class, idNewDealership);
    c.setDealership(newDealership);
    dealershipToDelete.getCars().remove(c);
}

session.update(dealershipToDelete);

session.flush();

session.delete(dealershipToDelete);

tx.commit();

session.close();
```

But it always deletes ALL cars. Even when I manage to make Hibernate update the cars with the new dealership. It updates them, and then it deletes them. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not adding the cars to the new dealership. You're not removing the cars from their old dealership.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the line that removed the car from the old dealership. I already tested it before I posted this. It still doesn't work.

Now I didn't add it to the new relationship. But now that I added this line on the loop (at the end of it):

`newDealership.getCars().add(c);`

It throws this exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [hibernate.entities.Car#14]

Comment: @MatiasMGS is your issue resolved?

Comment: Resolved by you! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refresh() the Dealership object before deleting it to reflect the changes made to its relationship with the Car class.Have slightly modified your code,try this:

```
Dealership dealershipToDelete = (Dealership) session.load(Dealership.class, idDealership);
Dealership newDealership = (Dealership) session.load(Dealership.class, idNewDealership);
for(Car c: dealershipToDelete.getCars().stream().filter(c -> c.isSold()).toArray(Car[]::new)){   
    c.setDealership(newDealership);
    newDealership.getCars().add(c);
}
session.flush(); //this will flush the updates to sold Car, with the new Dealership details 
session.refresh(dealershipToDelete); //this will load the updated "dealershipToDelete" without the 'Sold Car' object,the 'Unsold' ones will still be there
session.delete(dealershipToDelete); //this will delete the Dealership and its related unsold car objects.

tx.commit();

session.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try something like this :

first set the foreign key to nullable :

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="co_id" , nullable = true) 
    private Dealership dealership;

}
```

then you get the Id of dealershipToRemove:

```
int id = dealershipToRemove.getId();
```

then you delete all cars that have as dealership with the given id

```
query = session.createNativeQuery("delete from cars where co_id = :id and date is null");
query.setParameter(1,id);
query.executeUpdate();
```

then you break the relationship between dealershipToRemove and its cars :

```
dealershipToRemove .setCars(null);
session.remove(dealershipToRemove);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just remove all cars? So `session.remove(dealershipToRemove)` would have the exact same effect as all that. Adding `" and date is null"` to the query would fix it, but I was looking more for a solution using hibernate instead of queries, like SB's answer.